# What laser frequency is needed for the Doppler cooling of iron?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, laser-interaction, cold-atoms

What laser frequency is needed for Doppler cooling iron? How do you determine this frequency?

Comment: Have a look at  http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013APS..MARA41010B

Answer (score 0):

> How do you determine [the] frequency [needed to Doppler-cool some given atom]?

Basically, you need a frequency that matches a transition between two states, $|a⟩$ and $|b⟩$, where an atom in the excited state $|b⟩$ will decay only back to $|a⟩$ with only a negligible branching ratio to other states (or where you've implemented additional optical-pumping lasers to get any atoms that decay to other states back into your closed $|a⟩ \leftrightarrow |b⟩$ loop).

Generally, this is a laborious task, with few guarantees that it can be done with a convenient combination of laser sources, and it needs to be done on a case-by-case basis.

For iron, [this conference abstract](http://hdl.handle.net/2268/152840) and [this unavailable reference](http://hdl.handle.net/2268/198816) seem to contain schemes that describe laser cooling of iron, but their content doesn't seem to be available, and that seems to be all there is in the open literature at the moment.